# how to add newuser in mongoose data base in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am following the course "learn nodejs by building 10 projects". I have coded the same way as my instructor, but when I am adding a new user to the mongo database its not adding everything except `{"__v": 0}`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');

var db = mongoose.connection;

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    profileimage: {
        type: String
    }

});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser,callback){
    newUser.save(callback);
}
```

//this is how im creating user

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 =  req.body.password2;

  var multer = require('multer');
  var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });

  // Check for Image Field
  if(req.files && req.files.profileimage){
      console.log('uploading File...');

      // File Info
      var profileImageOriginalName = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
      var profileImageName = req.files.profileimage.name;

      var profileImageMime = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
      var profileImagePath = req.files.profileimage.path;
      var profileImageExt = req.files.profileimage.extension;
      var profileImageSize = req.files.profileimage.size;
  } else {
      // Set a Default Image
      var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
  }

var newUser = new User({
          name: name,
          email: email,
          username: username,
          password: password,
          profileImage: profileImageName
      });

          // Create User
          User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
              if(err)throw err;
              console.log(user);
          });

          //Success Message
          req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and may log in');

          res.location('/');
          res.redirect('/');
  //}
});
```

please check the code and see where I'm going wrong

Comment: How are you calling `createUser `?

Comment: Please show your code that invokes createUser

Answer (score 2):

That result in mongoose means you are saving a user without values.
You need to save an user for example like this:

```
let user= new User({

    userName: value,

    userPassword: value

  });

user.save();
```

or show a bit more how your trying to pass the values so we can check the best approach for it.

Comment: Hello Rahul for what i see you have an error in the user schema, note that your saving the callback not the newUser , try to change it and see if it fixes. Last line where you export the createUser your doing this: **newUser.save(callback);** , try to do only **newUser.save()**; to see if it fixes

Comment: Rahul can you see if the data is going  on submit ? check it on inspection with your browser to see if the user is going on post request. Also try to save directly instead of using the function your create. comment the code `// Create User
          User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
              if(err)throw err;
              console.log(user);
          });` and directly do `newUser.save();` and do some console.log from the variables to see if they have any value aswell

Answer (score 0):

Try this using your custom method `createUser`

```
let userModel= new User();
let data = {username:'alpha',password:'beta',name:'gamma'};

userModel.createUser(data,(err,doc) => {

if(err){
console.log(err);
}
console.log('saved');

})
```

Comment: im already doing this but i seem to get empty values in mongoose db

Answer (score 0):

just add `newUser.save()` after creating it